# create a view with multiple tables with NO joins

Tags: sql-server, view

I would like to create a view of multiple tables but no joins:

```
SELECT *
Table1, Table2, Table 3
```

But the Server is changing this to:

```
Select *
Table1 CROSSJOIN Table2 CROSSJOIN Table3
```

Is this not possible?

I have 4 tables... Products, Forms, Specifications and a fourth where the primary keys of the other three make up Product_Form_Specification.  I'd like to show all specifications that are not found in Product_Form_Specifications but I need to be able to add where parameters to restrict the Form and Product. I also need to be able to select the FormNumber and ProductID.  I have...

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000
      s.Commerce_SpecificationID
         ,s.Commerce_Spec_Name
         ,p.ProductID
         ,f.FormNumber
  FROM Commerce.dbo.Commerce_Specifications s
       , Commerce.dbo.Products p
       , Commerce.dbo.Commerce_Forms f
  WHERE s.Commerce_SpecificationID NOT IN 
                     (SELECT s2.Commerce_SpecificationID
                     FROM Commerce.dbo.Commerce_Specifications s2
                     INNER JOIN [Commerce].[dbo].[Commerce_Product_Form_Specification] pfs on pfs.SpecificationID = s2.Commerce_SpecificationID
                     INNER JOIN Commerce.dbo.Products p2 on pfs.ProductID = p2.ProductID
                     INNER JOIN Commerce.dbo.Commerce_Forms f2 on pfs.FormNumber = f2.FormNumber
                     WHERE p2.ProductID = p.ProductID 
                           AND f2.FormNumber = f.FormNumber)
```

This works fine as a query but the server changes it when I save it as a view.

EDIT: I don't know what I was doing wrong earlier, but this works fine.  Thank you for you help. I did learn about "," being cross joins.

Comment: What kind of relationship do these tables have? Also, what kind of structure do these tables have, and what is your desired output? If your table structures are the same, or similar, you can use UNIONs. Otherwise, you have to use joins.

Comment: Actually, `table1, table2` is a `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? From what I can see, JOIN is the right tool for the job here.

Comment: I have edited my original post to expand on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Oh boy.  I must not be getting enough sleep.  This works fine.. I don't know what I was doing wrong earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`,` is an older method of joining... it's a join without typing out "join".

Technically you could still do this, but it's easiest if all tables have the same schema.

```
select column1, column2, columnFromTable1Only
from table1
union all select column1, column2, null as columnFromTable1Only
from table2
```

in the above example, `table1` and `table2` have like `column1` and `column2` columns, however only `table1` has `columnFromTable1Only`. In this unioning instance `table2` needs to have *something* in that columns position, so `null` is used.

Comment: Which version of the standard deprecated `,` for cross joins?

Comment: @ShannonSeverance /shrug I was only relaying what I had heard so oops if that is misinformation.  With a quick google however: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: I agree that avoiding SQL-89 style joins and using SQL-92 style joins is a good thing. You won't get any from argument there. Here's an old post about what is being deprecated and what is not, with respect to old style joins: http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2008/09/13/deprecation-of-old-style-join-syntax-only-a-partial-thing.aspx